# How to set cookie to frontend with cross domain from firebase cloud http functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, session-cookies

I was trying to implement cross-domain authentication for my domain and other sub-domains. Currently, my backend is running through firebase cloud functions. So, my backend domain is like `https://my-region-firebase-project-id.cloudfunctions.net`.

I was adding the cookie like this:

```
res.cookie("foo", "bar", {
    domain: "mydomain.com",
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 1209600000,
    sameSite: "None",
    secure: true
});
```

This wasn't set the cookie to my front end. Saying *This attempt to set cookie via set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid regards to the current host url*

I even tried to put a dot before the domain like this: `.mydomain.com`. But still the same error.

I can't add a custom domain to my firebase cloud functions, since firebase doesn't support a custom domain for other regions except *us-central1*.

Did I missing something or not? Or is there any workaround with it?

**NB:** I am able to set cookies from the cloud function, the problem is the function domain and my frontend domain is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can map Firebase Hosting paths to Cloud Functions!

Your Firebase Hosting site can have a custom domain connected. ex: example.com. Once done, you can update the hosting configuration in `firebase.json` to add custom rewrites/redirects.

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Directs all requests from the page `/bigben` to execute the `bigben` function
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/bigben",
    "function": "bigben"
  } ]
}
```

Create a custom rewrite to one of your Firebase Functions. eg. `example.com/authenticate` -> `myAuthenticationFunction`.

See more details here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions